# haltonset: understanding skip and leap

Tags: matlab, random

If i read the doc of how to construct a [Halton quasi-random point set](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/haltonsetclass.html) and it mentions that it's possible to 'skip' the first values and then retain the 'leap' values.

Don't understand what the 'skip' and 'leap' really mean.

Have tried the following:

```
>> p = haltonset(1,'Skip',50,'Leap',10); d = haltonset(1,'Skip',51,'Leap',9);
>> p(2:10), d(1:9)
ans =
0.7344
0.0703
0.7891
0.4766
0.5859
0.1797
0.9922
0.3164
0.6602

ans =
0.7969
0.7344
0.8828
0.5391
0.8516
0.6484
0.9609
0.6172
0.7539

>> p(2:10) == d(1:9)
ans =

 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
```

Thought that it might be that that this would save 10 values to p and 9 to d. Also thought that d would have the same values as p. But this was not the case.

I then tested if the 'leap' would be the same as a normal way to make a vector 
  - ex: (1:leap:10)

```
>> p = haltonset(1,'Skip',50,'Leap',1); d = haltonset(1,'Skip',50,'Leap',2);
>> p(1:2:10)==d(1:5)
ans =
 1
 0
 0
 0
 0

>> p = haltonset(1,'Skip',0,'Leap',1); d = haltonset(1,'Skip',0,'Leap',2);
>> p(1:2:10)==d(1:5)
ans =
 1
 0
 0
 0
 0
```

but this seemed not to be the case..

Can anybody give a plain English explanation of how to interpreted the 'skip' and 'leap' variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the following description to be very clear [quoting this [documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/br5k9hi-8.html#bsgdinv-1)]:

> Imagine a simple 1-D sequence that produces the integers from 1 to 10.
>   This is the basic sequence and the first three points are [1,2,3]:
>
> [image: sequence]
>
> Now look at how Scramble, Leap, and Skip work together:
>
> - **Scramble**: Scrambling shuffles the points in one of several
>     different ways. In this example, assume a scramble turns the sequence
>     into 1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8,10. The first three points are now [1,3,5]:
>
> [image: Scramble]
>
> - **Skip**: A Skip value specifies the number of initial points to
>     ignore. In this example, set the Skip value to 2. The sequence is now
>     5,7,9,2,4,6,8,10 and the first three points are [5,7,9]:
>
> [image: Skip]
>
> - **Leap**: A Leap value specifies the number of points to ignore for
>     each one you take. Continuing the example with the Skip set to 2, if
>     you set the Leap to 1, the sequence uses every other point. In this
>     example, the sequence is now 5,9,4,8 and the first three points are
>     [5,9,4]:
>
> [image: Leap]

#### EDIT:

Let me show with an example:

```
%# create 1D sequences (x: picked, .: ignored)
p00 = haltonset(1,'Skip',0,'Leap',0);   %# xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
p50 = haltonset(1,'Skip',5,'Leap',0);   %# .....xxxxxxxxxx
p02 = haltonset(1,'Skip',0,'Leap',2);   %# x..x..x..x..x..
p52 = haltonset(1,'Skip',5,'Leap',2);   %# .....x..x..x..x

%# each pair of these are equal
[p50(1:10) p00(6:15)]     %# skip vs. noskip
[p02(1:5) p00(1:3:13)]    %# leap vs. noleap
[p52(1:4) p00(6:3:15)]    %# skip+leap vs. noskip+noleap
```

In general:

```
skip = 50;
leap = 10;
p00 = haltonset(1,'Skip',0,'Leap',0);
p = haltonset(1,'Skip',skip,'Leap',leap);

num = 9;
[p(1:num) p00(skip+1:leap+1:num*leap+num-leap+skip)]
```